How do I calculate the error propagation for an estimated parameter?
Assume that I have a resistor with an unknown resistance R. I measure the current trough it, I, and the voltage across it, U.
I can then estimate R:
$$
\hat{R} = \frac{U}{I}
$$
Let us assume I get the following result:
$$
\hat{R} = \frac{5V}{100mA} = 50 \Omega
$$
But how certain is this estimate?
Let us assume that the uncertainty in U is: $U \pm \delta U$ where $\delta U = 1mV$ and that the uncertainty in I is: $I \pm \delta I$ where $\delta I = 1mA$.
How do I calculate the the uncertainty in R ($R \pm \delta R$)?
Taylor approximation:
$$
R \approx R_0 + \frac{\partial R}{\partial U}dU + \frac{\partial R}{\partial I}dI 
$$
Definition of variance:
$$
Var[R] = E[(R - \mu_R)^2] = E[(R - R_0)^2] = E[(\frac{\partial R}{\partial U}dU + \frac{\partial R}{\partial I}dI)^2] \approx E[(\frac{\partial R}{\partial U}dU)^2 + (\frac{\partial R}{\partial I}dI)^2]
$$
where second order terms ($dUdI$) have been omitted.
Now
$$
E[dU]=E[U - \mu_U]= \sigma_U
$$
and
$$
E[dI]=E[I - \mu_I]= \sigma_I
$$
Therefore:
$$
\sigma_R^2 \approx 
(\frac{\partial R}{\partial U}\sigma_U)^2 + 
(\frac{\partial R}{\partial I}\sigma_I)^2
= (\frac{\sigma_U}{I})^2 + (\frac{U\sigma_I}{I^2})^2
= (\frac{5e-4}{0.1})^2 + (\frac{5*5e-4}{0.1^2})^2 
$$
$$
\sigma_R \approx 5e-4\sqrt{10^2+500^2} = 0.25
$$
Is my derivation above correct?
However one practical problem remains;
R is NOT normally distributed! In fact no simple analytical expression exists for the distribution of R.
The same will be true for many other problems.
How can I find a 95 % interval around $\mu$ for an unknown distribution where I only know $\mu$ and $\sigma$?
I suspect the answer is that I can not. If so the error propagation approach above seem fundamentally flawed for real world problems?
However I ran a Monte Carlo simulation and found:
R_min=4.951e+01,R_max=5.050e+01

which is almost the same as predicted by $R=\mu_R \pm 2*\sigma_R$!
Just dumb luck? Or does the Central limit theorem come into action here?
Here is my code:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mu_U = 5
sigma_U = 5e-4

mu_I = 0.1
sigma_I = 5e-4

N = 100*1000
U = np.random.normal(mu_U, sigma_U, N)
I = np.random.normal(mu_I, sigma_I, N)

R = U/I

R_min = np.percentile(R, 2.5)
R_max = np.percentile(R, 97.5)

print(f"R_min={R_min:.3e},R_max={R_max:.3e}")

plt.hist(R, bins=1000)
plt.show()

(1)
Propagation of uncertainty

If there is uncertainty in I you're going to need additional assumptions that it doesn't contain 0, otherwise, things will go sideways. The differential approximations you're proposing will assume a locally linear error, that's not necessarily appropriate.
Where do you derive the error propagation expression from?

I assume that such differential approximations will be first order approximations akin to a truncated Taylor expansion? I have guessed the error propagation expression from the document I refer to. However the derivation in that document I do not understand at all. It seems very non rigorous and poorly motivated. I would like to see a correct error propagation expression for my case along with a fairly rigorous derivation of it. Or maybe not so rigorous. I am quite good at calculus and linear algebra, but not very good at statistics (Msc in Physics).

Since you're good at Calculus, you will understand that the radius of convergence of the Taylor expansion of $1/(I+\delta I)$ is only $|I|,$ so if there is much of a chance of getting close to or beyond that boundary, the Taylor expansion will fail (dramatically).  That's the principal consideration in your application.
